# CSS: Cancelling properties at the start and end of a list

Tags: css, menu, styling

I have a menu list.  I'm not using UL/LI, just nested DIV's.  There are graphic separators between the menu items.  The first item in the list needs to suppress the left padding; the last item needs to suppress the right padding and the graphic separator.  Here's the CSS:

```
.platformItem {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 12px;
  background: url(/includes/themes/02RWO/images/assets/separator.gif) no-repeat top right;
}
.platformItem .first {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
.platformItem .last {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div id="platformMenu">  
  <div class="platformItem first"><a href="">All</a></div>
  <div class="platformItem"><a href="">Windows</a></div>
  <div class="platformItem"><a href="">Mac</a></div>
  <div class="platformItem"><a href="">Linux</a></div>
  <div class="platformItem last"><a href="">Web</a></div>
  <div class="Clear"></div>
</div>
```

I was hoping I could do the suppression of certain properties using *modifier* classes.  Is this possible?  Is there a better way to do this?

Thx.

Comment: Some minor nits about your html: (1) this looks like a <ul> to me, masquerading as a bunch of div's (2) you don't need classes assigned for the menu items, thats what descendant selectors are for: div#platformMenu div { padding: 0 12px; etc. }

Comment: No quibbles with your nits, Jon.  Chances are good I'll be switching to UL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't need JS after all.  .first and .last aren't downstream from .platformItem, but from #platformMenu.  (I should've seen this.)  New code:

```
#platformMenu .first {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
#platformMenu .last {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Oh, right. I thought you were trying to get rid of the .first and .last classes, too. You don't need .first if you're targeting IE7+, you can use #platformMeu div:first-child for that.

Comment: +1 because this is the surer bet in most environments if you have control over the markup.

Comment: your !important-s are not needed because your specificity is sufficient to override the current declaration specificity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [first-child](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_first-child.asp) pseudo-selector in modern browsers. [last-child isn't supported in IE7 or IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t37), though. You can also look at [jQuery's enhanced selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lastChild):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("div span:last-child")
    .css({color:"red", fontSize:"80%"})
});
```

Comment: Yes, in an ideal world, we'd only be dealing with modern browsers.  What's the solution for this barnyard world we live in?

Comment: Yes, that would work.  But I'm _just_ starting this layout: I was hoping to do it in CSS, and not have to resort to JS for some time...

Would going with UL/LI bring any benefits?

(And, BTW, thx for your help.)

Comment: The benefit UL/LI brings is to make clearer to yourself and any maintainers that the items are a list; that's the argument for semantics. If you don't care about semantics, you can put *any* block-level item in a DIV, and *any* inline item in a span (and then it's harder to understand the *meaning* of those elements). Other than that, CSS can select the elements whether they're LIs or DIV/DIVs. Agree with John Galloway -- the platformItem classes on the inner divs/list items are unnecessary. For compatibility, you need at least the 'last' class, as :last-child isn't supported in IE.

Comment: So the problem with UL/LI is that you need to add a number of properties to strip away the default styling before you can get to what you want.  But I'm all for semantics, Val; so I'll keep the UL/LI I just switched to.